# coil whine on kubuntu when idle

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, power-management, kubuntu

My pc has Kubuntu 17.04 and windows 10 setup with dual boot.

When i boot to kubuntu as soon as the login screen shows i hear high pitch coil whine sound from my pc.

I disabled all the power states on my bios (i know it can cause it). It didn't help.

whenever theres a little load on the cpu the noise stops.

Needless to say it **doesn't happen on windows 10**.

My specs:

- cpu: core i5-2500k
- mobo: Z68AP-D3

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the answer to this problem.

I knew that some CPUs of Sandy Bridge family had coil whine issue when stepping down to C3 power state. That can be solved easily by disabling C3 power state from bios.

The thing is that for some reason kubuntu ignores this option in the bios.

The solution is to add this line `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` to the file: `/etc/default/grub`

As explained in this post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/749349/how-to-set-intel-idle-max-cstate-1

Cheers.